# How to get the full request URL in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, url

We are using disconnected architecture. Front end is ExtJs and backend we are using handlers (.ashx). Suppose i give url as "https://appdomain.com/#settings/department/sso" how can i get the full url name from backend .
    I tried using  HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri but it return only 
    "https://appdomain.com", Suppose i give "https://appdomain.com/loginpage.aspx"
    this we can easily retrieve using HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.
    Does any one tried this please.

Comment: Take a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346489/how-do-i-get-the-url-part-after-a-from-httprequestbase

Comment: @Amit as per my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get the #settings/department/sso part.
Nothing after the # is sent to the server.

Comment: Thanks Alex. But when i give response.redirect("https://appdomain.com/#settings/department/sso") it redirect to correct path. So i should get the path also rt?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment

Comment: Sorry i mean-  when i give response.redirect("https://appdomain.com/#settings/department/sso") it redirect to correct path. So i should get the path from the backend  rt?

Comment: yes, because you're sending that FROM server side. There is no way of getting anything after the # from a visited page